# Sitecore Error: Could not load type 'Sitecore.Web.Application'

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I am very new to Sitecore development but the error I am receiving is kind of a very common nature I believe.

What I am facing is a weird Parser error. When I am trying to compile my project it is showing build succeeded. When I try to run the application it gives error like below right in Global.asax:

[image]

I am using .Net framework 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012 for this application.

The error is quite familiar as I have seen many posts similar to this error, but none could be of any help. I am hesitant to believe that it is specific to Sitecore.

Any advise would be highly appreciated. In case this question needs an improvement, please ask.

**UPDATE**

[image: Below DLLs I have in my project's bin folder for Sitecore]

Comment: Can you outline what you have checked already? For example, have you verified that the Sitecore DLLs are in the bin folder of your web application where you are running this site?

Comment: @Jay S: Please see an UPDATE in my question to see list of DLLs I have in my bin folder.

Comment: @Binoy, have you perform any upgrade? Make sure that the `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` version is correct. Also, you can dotpeek the Sitecore.Kernel in the bin folder and see if the namespace `Sitecore.Web.Application` is present

Comment: I would recommend comparing your bin folder against a clean install of 7.2 and make sure you have all the dependent assemblies installed.